# Which free software to use for pinpointing details on an image (and write notes on it)?

Tags: chrome, photography, highlighting

Which (free) software can I use to label/pinpoint details on a picture, as small as the details on the painting  [Netherlandish Proverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlandish_Proverbs) by Pieter Brueghel the Elder?

Preferably a software...

- ...containing small, round dots with different radii, and not thumbtacks like you have on My Maps from Google Maps, as having more than 125 thumbtacks on the painting above would look really ugly. 
  And having a solution to make hidden pinpoints stand out, with for example a separate list with the pinpoints in the picture, like you have on the left side of My Maps on Google Maps. And making dots different colors in case a white/transparant-ish dot is put on a white background.
- ...having my notes on the side of the picture, and not apppearing as a word balloon in the picture when I hover or click on a particular pinpoint. Mostly because a) it would overlap many other parts of the picture b) it would be handy if I want to make notes as long as one page, for example when pinpointing countries and cities and write notes about it.
- ...having the ability to switch to other pictures by pressing on the left and right arrows on your keyboard like you do with your personal photos in your Map on your taskbar. For example, when I want to pinpoint countries and cities of the continents of the world and put notes on it, I would like to switch to other continents by pressing the arrows on the keyboard.
- ...from Google Drive or Chrome Web Store/Chrome Extension, mostly because of easiness of navigation. (But not necessary if other external software has better quality)